# Common core for unbounded operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics, unbounded-operators

Suppose that $\mathcal H$ is a Hilbert space representing some physical system, $H$ is the Hamiltonian for the system, and $A$ is some observable for the system, that is, some unbounded self-adjoint operator on $\mathcal H$.  How restrictive is the assumption that $H$ and $A$ share some common core?  I believe this is the same assumption as saying that there is a dense subspace $M$ of $\mathcal H$ for which $H\upharpoonright M$ and $A\upharpoonright M$ are both essentially self-adjoint operators.  Is this an assumption that occurs naturally?

Comment: There's no mathematical reason for this to happen, but if by "naturally" you mean something like "in typical situations of physical relevance" and $\mathcal H= L^2$, then indeed $M=C_0^{\infty}$ works for the typical observables. (As a mathematical question, this seems too vague to admit meaningful answers.)

Comment: I guess one should interpret my question as asking if this occurred as an assumption of a theorem, would the theorem be silly because the assumptions hardly ever applied?